# properties file, {0} behind text is also displayed

Tags: eclipse, properties, internationalization, sapui5

I just created a properties file where I store my text.
In this [SAP Walkthrough](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/df86bfbeab0645e5b764ffa488ed57dc.html)

for SAPUI5 the wrote the code like this

```
showHelloButtonText=Say Hallo
helloMsg=Hello {0}
```

The {0} is for the case that I want to set more parameters. But now the pop-up also displays the {0}. So the output is:

```
Hello {0}
```

The properties file is just a "File" in eclipse with the suffix ".properties", if this could help.

Thanks for any hints :)

Answer (score 0):

Final result can be seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OGmJimjF2YZ46mv6DsF2?p=preview

What I did was the following:

When you want to bind a String with placeholders to a control in a view, you have to provide a formatter.

The formatter takes the placeholder String (`Hello {0}`) and the filler String and combines them

```
formatMsg: function(sMsg, sValue) {
  return jQuery.sap.formatMessage(sMsg, sValue);
}
```

This formatter has to be called when your element is rendered, so you have to add it to your binding

```
<Label text="{
  parts:[
    {path:'i18n>helloMsg'},
    {path:'/recipient/name'}
  ], formatter:'.formatMsg'}"
/>
```

The formatter takes two arguments, so we have to provide two values: The placeholder String and the value of the model.

Answer (score -1):

The example in SAPs Walkthrough shows you both ways how to set the text of your message.

The first would be a static text, defined by:

```
helloMsg = Hello
```

The second option would be to use the {} brackets. This is a reference to different language options saved within a file in your workspace.
When you change the language of your browser it will then display different languages as set in your file.